# What are the difference between Mongo URL and Mongo localhost connection?

Tags: mongodb

Sorry i'm new to MongoDB so I'm so confused between

```
mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.accdl.mongodb.net/website?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

and

```
mongodb://[port]:27017/[database_name]
```

what's difference and how is it impact our code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, as mongodb.com in https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/srv-connection-strings/   said :

> What is this mongodb+srv syntax?
> Well, in MongoDB 3.6 we introduced the concept of a seed list that is specified using DNS records, specifically SRV and TXT records. You will recall from using replica sets with MongoDB that the client must specify at least one replica set member (and may specify several of them) when connecting. This allows a client to connect to a replica set even if one of the nodes that the client specifies is unavailable.

and :

> Note that without the SRV record configuration we must list several nodes (in the case of Atlas we always include all the cluster members, though this is not required). We also have to specify the ssl and replicaSet options.

then in short words , mongodb +srv  syntax , is way to connect to mongodb database , released starting from mongodb 3.6 , and allows you connect to the whole replicaset including all nodes , instead of mention a specific node in the traditional connection way .

Comment: Is it okay if i used mongoDB localhost connection in my project as MONGODB_URL in .env?

Comment: I prefer to use the same way you are planning to use in production, to avoid the errors coming from changing the connection method because there are some extra configs mentioned in SRV way like: `retryWrites=true&w=majority` this config will affect the way of writing the data, anyway this is a bit advanced matter so if you are a newcomer to MongoDB you can start in this way for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think `mongodb+srv` is used when you are using cluster and one instance of db
both of them will work for one instance but I think `mongodb` is work only for one instance